# Add external project to my iphone app in xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

Just starting to poke around iPhone development.  I am trying to add an external project/library to mine (specifically the ASIHTTPRequest, http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

I am at a bit of a loss as to how I go about actually adding this dependency to my project.  I come from a Visual Studio/C# world, and in Visual Studio I know I would "Add Existing Project" to my solution file and then add a reference to the new project to my own.  Or, alternatively, reference the DLL directly if it is already built.

The ASIHttpRequest project is on GitHub, and provides full source code.  I just don't have any idea about how to actually get this dependency into my own project.  I tried "Project -> Add To Project", and just selected the folder ASIHTTPRequest extracted out into.  I see it as a sub-folder to my project now... but get a ton of build errors.  I removed everything but the .h and .m files from this subfolder, and now I don't get any build errors from those resources anymore, but trying to reference a ASIHTTPRequest object in my own project gives "undeclared" errors.

Am I missing something here?  Can I not of these .h and .m files in subfolders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You just need to #import the ASIHTTPRequest header in the file where you want to use it. You do have to make sure you've met all the [dependencies specified on the ASI site](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions), but once you've done that, everything should work right by just doing an import like you've described. Once all that is set and everything is compiled, add this:

```
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
```

to the top of the file where you want to use the library.

Comment: Duh, I should have known that.  Thanks!